# Chakra UI Tag Multi-part component styling

Tags: chakra-ui

I'm trying to style the Chakra UI Tag component, but only the styles for the container part work. Why is the styling for the label part not working?

```
baseStyle: {
    container: {
      bg: 'red',
    },
    label: {
      color: 'white',
      lineHeight: 3
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [docs](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/data-display/tag#props), there is default variant set to "subtle". If you're using default variant, you probably have to change default style (baseStyle) for that variant (because variant styles overrides baseStyle) =>

```
Tag: {
 variants: {
  subtle: {
   "your default style code here"
  },
 },
},
```